# Check common rows between two dataframes and replace the matched rows of second dataframe, with the values of df1

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames, Let's say df1 and df2. Both data frames have the same column named URL and Age. I want to check if df1['URL'] in df2['URL'], then replace the df2['Age'] with df1['Age'] for the matched row and keep the remaining rows in df2 without any change.

df1

```
URL          Category                         Age     
google.com  [IAB19, Technology & Computing]   A
youtube.com [IAB25, Non-Standard Content]     H
facebook.co [IAB14, Society]                  A
amazon.com  [IAB22, Shopping]                 M
wpedia.org  [IAB5, Education]                 E
```

df2

```
URL          Category         Age     
google.com  [IAB19, BBCA]     T
youtube.com [IAB25, AACB]     T
facebook.co [IAB14, HLGB      T 
amazon.com  [IAB22, ETCL]     T
wpedia.org  [IAB5, J TCL]     T
example1.com [LHTB, 2213]     A
example2.com [OPCL, 9909]     A
example3.com [PPRS, 7656]     A
```

Now, I want to check if any URL in the df1['URL'] exists in df2['URL'], I want to replace df2['Age'] with df1['Age'] and keeping the uncommon URLS without any change.

So, the expected output will be:

df3

```
URL          Category         Age     
google.com  [IAB19, BBCA]     A
youtube.com [IAB25, AACB]     H
facebook.co [IAB14, HLGB      A
amazon.com  [IAB22, ETCL]     M
wpedia.org  [IAB5, J TCL]     E
example1.com [LHTB, 2213]     A
example2.com [OPCL, 9909]     A
example3.com [PPRS, 7656]     A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `map` + `fillna`:

map allows us to replace age for common URLs and then `.fillna` restores the value for the URLs which had no match. This assumes `URL` is a unique key in `df1`:

```
df3 = df2.copy()
df3['Age'] = df3.URL.map(df1.set_index('URL').Age).fillna(df3.Age)

#            URL            Category Age
#0    google.com  [IAB19, BBCA]        A
#1   youtube.com  [IAB25, AACB]        H
#2   facebook.co  [IAB14, HLGB         A
#3    amazon.com  [IAB22, ETCL]        M
#4    wpedia.org  [IAB5, J TCL]        E
#5  example1.com   [LHTB, 2213]        A
#6  example2.com   [OPCL, 9909]        A
#7  example3.com   [PPRS, 7656]        A
```